# Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having problems with my application being able to find my users table in my database.

rake db:test:prepare is not solving the problem for me. It doesn't do anything when I enter it.

```
Failures:

  1) Micropost
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Micropost
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'users'
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00319 seconds
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:13 # Micropost
rspec ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:14 # Micropost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have migrated your dev database just run `rake db:test:clone`

Comment: thank you!!! if you want you can help me with my next [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160257/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-chapter-10-listing-10-36-failing-test-because-its-differ)

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `rake db:migrate` **and** `rake db:test:prepare` like:

```
rake db:migrate db:test:prepare
```